# Clear ComboBox selected text

Tags: c#, winforms, drop-down-menu, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` control with the `DropDownStyle` properties set to `DropDownList`.
Once there is an item selected, how can I clear the selection from the `ComboBox` without deleting any Items in it ?

I'd normally use something like that:

```
myComboBox.Text.Clear();
```

But I can't do that.     Any idea how I could clear it ?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You could change `SelectedIndex` property:

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Comment: I'll try it.
The -1 index will be a `null` value?

Comment: Funny how comboBox.ClearText() and comboBox.Text.Clear() both don't work but comboBox.SelectedIndex = -1 does... It seems the API department needs a visit

Answer (score 24):

The only way I could get it to work:

```
comboBox1.Text = "";
```

For some reason ionden's solution didn't work for me.

Comment: The reason is that you have probably entered strings into your comboBox1, not Items.

Answer (score 10):

This is what you need:

`comboBox1.ResetText();`

Answer (score 3):

all depend on the configuration.
for me works

```
comboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

my configuration

```
DropDownStyle: DropDownList
```

(text can't be changed for the user)

Answer (score 3):

```
nameofcombobox.SelectedItem = -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you populate your Combobox with objects:

```
Combobox.SelectedItem = null;
```

Answer (score -1):

`comboBox1.Text = " ";`

This is the best and easiest way to set your `comboBox` back to default settings without erasing the contents of the `comboBox`.

Answer (score -1):

In c# if you make you comboBox configuration style `DropDownList` or `DropDown` then use both of them in this method to clear.

```
ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Answer (score -2):

Try specifying the actual index of the item you want erase the text from and set its `Text` equal to `""`.

```
myComboBox[this.SelectedIndex].Text = "";
```

or

```
myComboBox.selectedIndex.Text = "";
```

I don't remember the exact syntax but it's something along those lines.

Answer (score -2):

write the following code:

```
comboBox1.Items[comboBox1.SelectedIndex] = string.Empty;
```

Answer (score -3):

The following code will work:

```
ComboBox1.SelectedIndex.Equals(String.Empty);
```

Comment: This is a Boolean statement